# What's the difference between an Saas and an API. (SaaS vs Api)

Tags: saas

I would like to know what is the difference between a SaaS and an API. I feel like it's somehow the same. So let's say I building a *Rails or Flask api* can I say that I'm buiding a *Rails or Flask SaaS*?

saas: *Software as a Service (SaaS) is a software distribution model in which applications are hosted by a vendor or service provider and made available to customers over a network, typically the Internet.*([source](http://searchcloudcomputing.techtarget.com/definition/Software-as-a-Service))

api: API stands for Application Programming Interface and *it's simply a way to get information and pass information to trusted partners. Category. People & Blogs*.(google)

Comment: According to these definition, SAAS is a business term not a technical term.
It is confusing how technical people using SAAS expression as an alternative for API.
May be because they just like using new abbreviation terms!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Software as a Service is a complete application that hosts/supports multiple users from a single code base. Gmail, Hotmail, Dropbox, Google Drive, Stackoverflow - pretty much anything you are using online and is also used by multiple people *as a service*.

An API is just a way for others to build *on top of* your existing application. An API doesn't need SaaS, and APIs have been around a lot longer than the Internet itself.

If you are building an API, it generally means you need others to build on some data you are exposing through the API, or extend an application for which you are creating an API.  You may decide to host this API online simply for ease of use, and you may decide to host the *resources* online as well. Now your entire product API + resources + interface is an example of a *software that is being distributed as a service*.

However, you can perfectly use an API to create application that are completely offline. For example, you can create a new extension for Chrome or Firefox using the browser's API, but Chrome is not "SaaS".

Answer (score 4):

SaaS applications may provide a user interface. APIs are always programming interfaces. APIs do not necessarily work over a network, either.

Answer (score 1):

SaaS Interfaces & APIs
SaaS is short for software as a service. It is one of the more innovative new tools that has been developed for businesses. It is designed to help businesses integrate the applications they use into a format that they can use throughout their offices. One of the main things to consider is how the new software will work with your existing software, as well as with future software applications you may need to purchase.

In order to address this issue there is an option that will allow you to purchase a complete suite of applications that are designed to work together. Since this is not the optimal choice for all businesses there is also the option to have an open API that will allow the business to easily integrate future applications they purchase.

API
Inside a business all of the different software applications that are implemented for use need to work well with the existing software. It is a bad business practice to have one department use a software that the other departments do not use, or that will not work with the software the other departments have. This creates confusion among the different departments. SaaS API is designed to stop this problem and to create software packages that are designed to keep the lines of communication in the inner office open.

INTERFACE
SaaS interface is web based which makes it ideal for the small businesses. The small business will have access to the system from anywhere in the world. This removes the limitations that your older software systems placed on you.

Some businesses question how secure their data will be when they switch to a system like this. Basically the system takes the business processes used by the front office and those used in the back office and uses a third party system to tie the two together. The risk of data being compromised through the use of this system is no greater than any other web based application you may use. Every safeguard that can be used has been put into place to try and keep your information safe and secure